# dimplejs 100 percent stacked vertical bar with two values by date

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I have a 100% stacked chart in google charts that I want to convert to dimplejs.

The two y values are a combo of two percentage values that equal 100%, but I only have one percentage value and the second should be the bar completing the other part to equal up 100%

The x series is a month/year combination.

Here is a functional attempt but notice I essentially duped my data to match what the example was expecting.

```
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 900, 400);
    var data = [
        {'YRMO': '01-01-2014', 'halfit': 'first', 'Percent':'24'},
        {'YRMO': '02-01-2014', 'halfit': 'first', 'Percent':'76'},
        {'YRMO': '03-01-2014', 'halfit': 'first', 'Percent':'31'},
        {'YRMO': '04-01-2014', 'halfit': 'first', 'Percent':'69'},
        {'YRMO': '05-01-2014', 'halfit': 'first', 'Percent':'20'},
        {'YRMO': '06-01-2014', 'halfit': 'first', 'Percent':'70'},
        {'YRMO': '07-01-2014', 'halfit': 'first', 'Percent':'28'},
        {'YRMO': '08-01-2014', 'halfit': 'first', 'Percent':'70'},
        {'YRMO': '01-01-2014', 'halfit': 'second', 'Percent':'76'},
        {'YRMO': '02-01-2014', 'halfit': 'second', 'Percent':'24'},
        {'YRMO': '03-01-2014', 'halfit': 'second', 'Percent':'69'},
        {'YRMO': '04-01-2014', 'halfit': 'second', 'Percent':'31'},
        {'YRMO': '05-01-2014', 'halfit': 'second', 'Percent':'80'},
        {'YRMO': '06-01-2014', 'halfit': 'second', 'Percent':'30'},
        {'YRMO': '07-01-2014', 'halfit': 'second', 'Percent':'72'},
        {'YRMO': '08-01-2014', 'halfit': 'second', 'Percent':'30'},
        ];

  var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
  myChart.setBounds(65, 45, 505, 315)
  myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "YRMO");
  myChart.addPctAxis("y", "Percent");
  myChart.addSeries("halfit", dimple.plot.bar);
  myChart.addLegend(200, 10, 380, 20, "right");
  myChart.draw();
```

**And what I am struggling with is how I can make this work:**

```
    var data = [
        {'YRMO': '01-01-2014', 'Percent':'24'},
        {'YRMO': '02-01-2014', 'Percent':'76'},
        {'YRMO': '03-01-2014', 'Percent':'31'},
        {'YRMO': '04-01-2014', 'Percent':'69'},
        {'YRMO': '05-01-2014', 'Percent':'20'},
        {'YRMO': '06-01-2014', 'Percent':'70'},
        {'YRMO': '07-01-2014', 'Percent':'28'},
        {'YRMO': '08-01-2014', 'Percent':'70'}];
```

[My JSFiddle....](http://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/katm9e6s/)

Comment: Do you need to have bars for both parts (the percent given, and the remaining percent stretching to 100) or would it work to just have the original data without the remainders? (I guess I'm curious what it originally looked like in google charts)

Comment: Actually I was hoping to derive the second stack of bars from he first based the difference (value)...I am thinking of doing some sort of intercept reversal before the data is fed to dimple.chart(). But I wonder if there is a less mechanical way other than janking with my dataset.The chart in my jsfiddle looks like my google chart, just the method I used to make it is different and I am new to dimple, I'm sure I will figure out something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimple's percent axis works based off of the sum of the values for that series/category intersection, so it will only work if, like you said, you jank with the dataset and add the complement values. It should be pretty easy to generate the opposite values :

```
var data = [
    {'YRMO': '01-01-2014', 'Percent':'24'},
    {'YRMO': '02-01-2014', 'Percent':'76'},
    {'YRMO': '03-01-2014', 'Percent':'31'},
    {'YRMO': '04-01-2014', 'Percent':'69'},
    {'YRMO': '05-01-2014', 'Percent':'20'},
    {'YRMO': '06-01-2014', 'Percent':'70'},
    {'YRMO': '07-01-2014', 'Percent':'28'},
    {'YRMO': '08-01-2014', 'Percent':'70'}];
//add property for first half (or put directly in data if possible)
data.forEach(function(row){
   row.halfit = 'first';
});

//create second half
var opposites = data.map(function(row){
    return { "YRMO" : row.YRMO,
        "Percent": (100 - Number(row.Percent)),
        "halfit" : "second"
       };
});
//combine the two - concat returns a new array
var chartData = data.concat(opposites);
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, chartData);
...
//add order rule so original data is on bottom
var series = myChart.addSeries("halfit", dimple.plot.bar);
series.addOrderRule(['first', 'second']);
```

[image: chart with complement bars]

Otherwise, you could just graph the original values without the opposite bars by using a measure axis locked at 100 (this will only work because your values are already percents, however) :

```
  var yAxis = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Percent");
 yAxis.overrideMax = 100;
```

[image: chart with only original bars]

However it sounds like that won't work for your use case, but it is an option.

Comment: Thanks for the help...That solution looks workable :)